# React native Tabbar color change does not work

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, tabbar

I would like to change the color of the tabbar when clicking on it in react native. I tried with this code but it shows me the standard color on my iPhone. I searched for solutions but no one is working. Changing the tabBarLabel works but the color does not.
Could you help me?
Here is my code:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

<Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}
  tabBarBadgeStyle={{backgroundColor: '#0000ff', color:'green'}}
 
 tabBarOptions={{
   tabBarLabel: 'Test',
   style: { backgroundColor: 'orange'}
 }}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add tabBarOption in the navigator instead of screen ,

```
    <Tab.Navigator
          tabBarOptions: {
          activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
         labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 12,
               },
         style: {
       backgroundColor: 'blue',
           },
         }>
          <Tab.Screen
            name={variable.overViewScreen}
            component={Overview}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name={variable.homeScreen}
            component={DashboardRoot}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
```